# Redux : Reducer is not called

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am making a mobile app by React Native and Redux.

It seems that my actions, state are working properly because I did console.log them.

The issue here is that my reducer is not called.

I did log it on the console but there is no result.

I don't know what is causing this.

I try to fetch API data in Market.js

I'd really appreciated if anyone helps me.

my github repo : https://github.com/sj602/invescoin

code as following:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Stacks } from './utils/Navigation';
import {
  StyleSheet, Text, View,
} from 'react-native';
import { store } from './store';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Stacks />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

store.js

```
import {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  compose
} from 'redux';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import reducer from '../reducers';

// const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  // composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  // )
);
```

reducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import {
  GET_MARKET_CAP,
  GET_MARKET_CAP_SUCCESS,
  GET_MARKET_CAP_FAIL,
  GET_GLOBAL_INFO,
} from '../actions';


const initialState = {
  isFetching: null,
  data: '',
  hasError: false,
  errorMessage: null,
}

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_MARKET_CAP:
      console.log(2)
      return ;
    case GET_MARKET_CAP_SUCCESS:
      console.log('success')
    case GET_MARKET_CAP_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        marketCap: action.err
      }
    case GET_GLOBAL_INFO:
      console.log('action')
      return {
        ...state,
        bitcoinPercentage: action.bitcoinPercentage
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

actions.js

```
 import {
  GET_MARKET_CAP,
  GET_MARKET_CAP_SUCCESS,
  GET_MARKET_CAP_FAIL,
  GET_GLOBAL_INFO
} from './types.js';
import * as api from '../utils/api';

export const getMarketCap = (coin, currency) => dispatch => {
    return api.getMarketCap(coin, currency)
        .then(data => {
          dispatch({type: GET_MARKET_CAP_SUCCESS, data})
        })
        .catch(err => {
          dispatch({type: GET_MARKET_CAP_FAIL, err})
        })
}

export function getGlobalInfo() {
    return dispatch => {
      return api.getGlobalInfo().then(data => {
          dispatch({type: GET_GLOBAL_INFO, data})
        })
  }
}
```

types.js

```
export const GET_MARKET_CAP = 'GET_MARKET_CAP';
export const GET_MARKET_CAP_SUCCESS = 'GET_MARKET_CAP_SUCCESS';
export const GET_MARKET_CAP_FAIL = 'GET_MARKET_CAP_FAIL';
export const GET_GLOBAL_INFO = 'GET_GLOBAL_INFO';
export const GET_COIN_PRICE = 'GET_COIN_PRICE';
```

Market.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View, Text, TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView, TextInput
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  getMarketCap,
  getGlobalInfo,
} from '../actions/index';
import * as api from '../utils/api';
import { cryptoList } from '../utils/cryptoList';

class Market extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getMarketCap('bitcoin', 'KRW').then(data => data[0]['market_cap_krw'])
;
    this.props.getGlobalInfo();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {this.props.market}
        </Text>
        <Text>
          {this.props.bitcoinPercentage}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    market: state.market,
    bitcoinPercentage: state.bitcoinPercentage
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getMarketCap,
  getGlobalInfo
})(Market)
```

api.js

```
const Coinmarketcap_URL = `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/`;

const headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authentication': 'c23R30cm2jOOExyAsG6pf5Xxy4QwpndxaIMRs6aOZxIQoUlMVOv1tCQZL3jZz'
};

export const getMarketCap = (coin, currency) => {
  return fetch(
    `${Coinmarketcap_URL}ticker/${coin}/?convert=${currency}`,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers,
    }
  )
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(e => console.log('Error occurred : ', e))
}

export const getGlobalInfo = () => {
  return fetch(
    `${Coinmarketcap_URL}global/`,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers,
    }
  )
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(e => console.log('Error occurred : ', e))
}
```

Comment: I think your reducer **is** called, may only not hit your specific case statement with console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in [reducer.js L7](https://github.com/sj602/invescoin/blob/master/reducers/index.js#L7):

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import {
  GET_MARKET_CAP,
  GET_MARKET_CAP_SUCCESS,
  GET_MARKET_CAP_FAIL,
  GET_GLOBAL_INFO,
} from '../actions';  // <--- ../actions/index.js doesn't export these.
```

When you import from `../actions`, the exports are expected to be in the `index.js` file that is in that folder. The filenames you used to describe your issue don't match the actual filenames in your repository.

Instead, try `import { ... } from ../actions/types` since `types.js` is the file that actually exports those `const`s.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome. I'd recommend adding a JavaScript linter to your project -- it'll help you catch these kinds of errors quickly. Check out eslint, and the accompanying extension for your text editor so you can see issues like this as you code.

Comment: Okay! I will definitely use that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in market.js file

```
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux"

function mapDispatchToProps(dipatch) {
return bindActionCreators({
  getMarketCap,
  getGlobalInfo
}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Market)
```

Now it should work , you missed binding your function with dispatch

Comment: Thanks! I added bindActionCreators but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I couldn't help but notice that is your store.js there is no initial state for the reducers. In the react docs for the create store method:

```
createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])
```

Can you make an initial State and see if that works. So your code might look similar to this;

```
import {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  compose
} from 'redux';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import reducer from '../reducers';


initialState = {Initial State of Reducers}
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  intialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
);
```